# Combine data from multiple rows in SAS if multiple ids including adding some vars

Tags: sas

Hope you can help with an solution, either a SQL or data step.

I need to combine multiple rows if customer id is the same, and add some vars with code too.

I have following static variable containers:

```
%let FirstColSuffix=<Somecode1>
%let SecondColSuffix=#<SomeCode2>
%let ThirdColSuffix=#<SomeCode3>
```

Data have;

```
Customerid  Firstcol    Secondcol   Thirdcol
1   A1  A2  A3
2   B1  B2  B3
2   C1  C2  C3
2   D1  D2  D3
3   E1  E2  E3
3   F1  F2  F3
3   G1  G2  G3
3   H1  H2  H3
```

Data want;

```
Customerid  Firstcol    Secondcol   Thirdcol    Result
1   A1  A2  A3  A1<SomeCode1>A2#<SomeCode2>A3#<SomeCode3>
2   B1  B2  B3  B1<SomeCode1>B2#<SomeCode2>B3#<SomeCode3>
2   C1  C2  C3  B1<SomeCode1>B2#<SomeCode2>B3#<SomeCode3>C1<SomeCode1>C2#<SomeCode2>C3#<SomeCode3>
2   D1  D2  D3  B1<SomeCode1>B2#<SomeCode2>B3#<SomeCode3>C1<SomeCode1>C2#<SomeCode2>C3#<SomeCode3>D1<SomeCode1>D2#<SomeCode2>D3#<SomeCode3>
3   E1  E2  E3  E1<SomeCode1>E2#<SomeCode2>E3#<SomeCode3>
3   F1  F2  F3  E1<SomeCode1>E2#<SomeCode2>E3#<SomeCode3>F1<SomeCode1>F2#<SomeCode2>F3#<SomeCode3>
3   G1  G2  G3  E1<SomeCode1>E2#<SomeCode2>E3#<SomeCode3>F1<SomeCode1>F2#<SomeCode2>F3#<SomeCode3>G1<SomeCode1>G2#<SomeCode2>G3#<SomeCode3>
3   H1  H2  H3  E1<SomeCode1>E2#<SomeCode2>E3#<SomeCode3>F1<SomeCode1>F2#<SomeCode2>F3#<SomeCode3>G1<SomeCode1>G2#<SomeCode2>G3#<SomeCode3>H1<SomeCode1>H2#<SomeCode2>H3#<SomeCode3>
```

I only need output if last customer id (but with data from all matching customer id outputted in last row in column "result".

So in this example I need the line 1, 4 and 8

Can anyone help? :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `retain` and by-group processing. We'll continually concatenate `result` to itself for each row we read and carry that value forward. At the last customer ID, we'll output. At the first customer ID, `result` is reset.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by Customerid;

    length Result $500.;
    retain Result;

    if(first.Customerid) then call missing(Result);
    
    Result = cats(Result, FirstCol, "&FirstColSuffix", SecondCol, "&SecondColSuffix", ThirdCol, "&ThirdColSuffix");

    if(last.Customerid);
run;
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Stu

But I get an error at first.id

Comment: Is that because it should say if (first.customerid) and not if (first.id)   ??

Comment: That's right, sorry about that, I was using test data and forgot to update the variable. I corrected this in the post.

Comment: Thanks alot Stu - it works like a charm :-)